# ctypes: construct pointer from arbitrary integer

Tags: python, ctypes, pywin32

For low-level purposes, I need to construct a ctypes pointer from an arbitrary address, given as an integer. For instance:

```
INTP = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)
p = INTP(0x12345678) # i *know* this is the address
```

But all such attempts result in

```
TypeError: expected c_long instead of int
```

Is there anything I can do to overcome this? In case someone wonders why I need this, it's done so as to extract the `OVERLAPPED` struct from a `win32file.PyOVERLAPPED`, for integrating ctypes-exposed functions with win32file wrapped APIs.

Thanks,
-Tomer

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use `ctypes.cast(addr, type)`. I'll extend your example to acquire an address via a known object, to demonstrate:

```
INTP = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)
num = ctypes.c_int(42)
addr = ctypes.addressof(num)
print 'address:', addr, type(addr)
ptr = ctypes.cast(addr, INTP)
print 'pointer:', ptr
print 'value:', ptr[0]
```

Output:

```
address: 4301122528 <type 'int'>
pointer: <__main__.LP_c_int object at 0x1005decb0>
value: 42
```

Comment: @sebulba: and if it does, mark the answer as correct, please :)

Comment: what about **print('value:', ptr.contents)**